# WSO2 API Manager: Error adding test API (api with only root context)

Tags: api, wso2, wso2-api-manager

Our service provides a simple test API:
`GET /api/test/v1` which simply returns "Test Success"

Trying to add this to the WSO2 API Manager version 1.8.

```
Name: test
Context: test
Version: v1
Visibility: Public
```

Now what should be added under Resources? As the API does not have any sub-resources, tried adding as:

```
URL Pattern: /
Resource Name: /
```

When clicked "Implement", got the error `"Error while adding Swagger Definition for test-v1"`

Please suggest what is the right input for "Resources" in this case (where API has only a root context)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leave for default resource pattern. This will enable all HTTP verbs (ie: GET/PUT/POST/DELETE/OPTIONS) to accept all resource patterns.
Eg: URL Pattern: /*